# AG Grid expand rows on init

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datatables, ag-grid

i am working on an app that that is using aggrid.
data is received from server, stored into state, and fed to the aggrid [rowData]="rowData"

separate task receives the settings of my data, like: column widths, row expanded, row selected...
i can apply column widths on initial data, and later listen for events when column is resized and save that back,
but for the expanded, no such thing.
i have `onFirstDataRendered` and there i iterate and set the expanded node, but i want to this before, in init like, because this fires the `onRowGroupOpened(event: RowGroupOpenedEvent)` every time node is expanded, and i cant distinguish programmatically expand from user click.

can anyone suggest solution for expanding the rows in initial data prep? or distinguish expand event programmatically vs user click?

---

is there any other way to expand node except `node.setExpanded` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`groupDefaultExpanded`](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/grouping/#grid-grouping-properties) property to set the default group expansion settings at the start:

- `0`: Don't expand
- `1`: Expand all first level groups
- `2`: Expand up to second level groups
- `-1`: Expand all groups by default (what you need)

#### [Live Demo](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/FOPxXpUaWnIOZFye)

Comment: yes, but is so limited.
i want for example expand: first, fifth, and 11th node, and that is going to be saved, and load that on refresh of the page in the manner from my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ag-Grid on its own or with AdapTable?

If the latter then that has the ability to set which rows should be expanded when app launches - and will also automatically save any expanded rows for next reload.

I think its AdapTable rather than ag-Grid which is doing this but I'm not 100% sure.

See demo at https://demo.adaptabletools.com/layout/aggridgroupedlayoutdemo

Comment: thanks, it looks like the AdapTable tools is doing the job.
will check the pricing.